# Pandas: Extract the index of the rows that seem to have a float variable

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {3: {0: 'Total shareholders’ equity, beginning balances', 1: 'Total shareholders’ equity, beginning balances', 2: 'Total shareholders’ equity, beginning balances', 3: '$', 4: '90488', 9: '$', 10: '107147', 15: '$', 16: '134047'}} )
```

As you can see that index 4, 10, 16 are numbers. How can I extract these numbers automatically.

Note: As you can see this column contain strings as well as numbers but those numbers are read as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to numeric which will make invalid integers/floats into `NaN`. then drop the `NaN` and get the indices

```
pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce').dropna().index
```

Out:

```
Int64Index([4, 10, 16], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: It will convert values which are a) float & b) bool as well which might not be the incentive of OP

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mask to check if they are numeric:

```
df[df[3].str.isnumeric()]
```

results in:

```
    3
4   90488
10  107147
16  134047
```